# Cannot connect to my own Minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-java-edition-server

Me and my friend are trying to play Minecraft together. But as it seems, I can't connect to my own Minecraft server but my friend can. I have allowed it in my firewall among opening some ports in my router as well.

I'm hosting the server from the same computer I'm playing from.
What can cause this and how can this be fixed?

Comment: what (if any) error messages do you get in the client when you try to connect?

Comment: When trying to connect locally, are you using the router IP address or localhost as the server address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're hosting the server on your own computer then using `localhost` will work just fine.

Comment: Where do you enter that - is there a client or the regular browser will do?

Answer (score 3):

What IP are you connecting through? There are are 3 or 4 ways to do this.

- `localhost` can do, or connecting through your port directly. `localhost:25565`
- Also you can use your computers IP address. To find this, go to command prompt and type in `ipconfig` and click enter. Find your IP address, it should look something like `IPv4 Address: ###.###.###.###`. Except their will be your IP address there. Type in your IP address and you can optionally add the port number to this one also. `25565`.
- The last way is through your computer's IP. You can find it [here](http://www.whatsmyip.org/). Again you can type that IP in and also you can connect with just that or you can add the port again. `25565`

The first two options are only used if the server is run on your computer. The port can be binded to other port numbers. I could allow my Minecraft server on port 230467 if I wanted to. That only means people would have to type in this instead of my normal IP, `My.IP:230467`. Make sense? Need to know anything else? 
Also, check all your ports. Make sure they're open on the router itself, not just on your computer.

If someone posts something like this, I apologize. I have been distracted and didn't get a chance to post it sooner.

EDIT: It would really help if you tell us what pops up when you try connecting.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to connect to the server what error appears? And what IP are you trying to connect to?

If it's the same as your friends use try to connect to `localhost` or `*` like `localhost:25565` or `*:25565`.